# java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to my custom model class

Tags: object, casting, typecast-operator

Hello Everyone i am a bit new with hibernate query result and stuff as per my requirements i have to build a json result from following query i have my model class which i will be returning as json response, The query.getResult() returns me with object class but type casting is not working for me is there any alternate way for this.I want to map the query result with my custom Model Object.

```
 List<Object[]>  result = query.getResultList();
            ListIterator<Object[]> iter = result.listIterator();
            List<ReferFriend> refer=new ArrayList<>();
            while (iter.hasNext()){
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                ReferFriend referFriend=  (ReferFriend) (Object)iter.next();
                refer.add(referFriend);
            }
            return refer;
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `iter.next()` returns `Object[]`, but you are casting it to `ReferFriend`

Comment: @rkosegi yup i know it gives me object array and i have to map it to my custom model object that's my question how can i do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this Now.I stored the result as an object array and Iterated over it.I then explicitly casted each element to my pojo class elements.The problem i was facing earlier was the first parameter the query result was big integer and my pojo had Int field. Thanks  @rkosegi .

Answer (score 0):

`iter.next()` returns Object[], but you are casting it to `ReferFriend`

It looks like you need to extract data from array in order to construct your object.
There are couple of ways which comes to mind:

- Create constructor on `ReferFriend` which takes an `Object[]` as argument. Inside constructor assign your properties from that array (in this case, I recommend to declare your properties **final**)
- Construct `ReferFriend` using default (no arguments) constructor and assign property values from array using setters.
- Have a factory
- Fluent builder approach
- Others

Comment: Thanks already tried constructor that takes an object[] as argument will try the other approaches. cheers.